# Como generar un archivo excel desde una BD en CodeIgniter utilizando ajax

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

estoy realizando una funcion para descargar un reporte mediante un rango de fechas,
Tengo un boton que dice Reporte incidentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle clic en el boton, me muestra un formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionando el rango de fechas y al dar clicl en descargar entra a la funcion js

```
function descargarReporte() {
    console.log('hola metodo descargar reporte1');
    /*var formData = new FormData($('.serialize')[0]);
    console.log(formData);
    const fechaInicio = document.getElementById('fecha1').value;
    const fechaFin = document.getElementById('fecha2').value;
    console.log(fechaInicio);
    console.log(fechaFin);*/
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    $.ajax({
        url: path + 'IncidentesController/Reporte',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('.serialize').serialize(),
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res.mensaje);

            if (res.resultado) {
                // Crear un enlace y forzar la descarga
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = res.resultado;
                link.download = 'reporte.xlsx';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            } else {
                console.log('No se encontraron registros para exportar.');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Y esta funcion hace una peticion ajax al metodo reporte del controlador.

```
public function Reporte()
{
    $mensaje = 'ejecutando';
    $datos = $this->input->post();
    $rutaArchivoExcel = 'http://localhost/intimark/cache/reporte.xlsx';
    $this->load->library('export_excel');
    $result = $this->incidentes->exportar_excel($datos);
    #$result = $this->incidentes->exportar_excel();
    $this->export_excel->to_excel($result, $rutaArchivoExcel);
    #$response = array('mensaje' => $mensaje);
    $response = array('mensaje' => $mensaje, 'resultado' => $rutaArchivoExcel);
    echo json_encode($response);    
}
```

Este metodo, interactua con el metodo exportar_excel del modelo y trae los datos para guardarlos en la variable $result

```
public function exportar_excel($datos)
{
    $f1 = $datos['fecha1'];
    $f2 = $datos['fecha2'];
    $this->db->select('incidentes.titinc, incidentes.descripcion, incidentes.fecreg, incidentes.fecter, u1.nomusu, u2.nomusu, e.desest, incidentes.notas');
    $this->db->join('usuarios u1', 'u1.id_usuario = incidentes.id_ususol');
    $this->db->join('usuarios u2', 'u2.id_usuario = incidentes.id_usures');
    $this->db->join('estados_incidentes e', 'e.id_estado = incidentes.id_estado');
    $this->db->where(array("fecreg >=" => $f1, "fecreg <=" => $f2));
    #$this->db->where(array("fecreg >=" => "2023-06-01", "fecreg <=" => '2023-06-15'));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->result();
}
```

El problema aparece en el controlador, especificamente cuando se asigna la variable result a la clase export_excel, si comento esa linea me genera un archivo vacio. Alguien me puede ayudar para generar el archivo?

La libreria export_excel es una libreria generica

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  

class export_excel{

    function to_excel($array, $filename) {
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.xls');
        header('Content-type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Pragma: public');
        print "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
        $h = array();
        foreach($array->result_array() as $row){
            foreach($row as $key=>$val){
                if(!in_array($key, $h)){
                    $h[] = $key;   
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<table><tr>';
        foreach($h as $key) {
            $key = ucwords($key);
            echo '<th style="border:1px #888 solid;background-color:#58ACFA;color:white;">'.$key.'</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        foreach($array->result_array() as $row){
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach($row as $val)
                $this->writeRow($val);   
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

    }

    function writeRow($val) {
        echo '<td style="border:1px #888 solid;color:#555;">'.$val.'</td>';              
    }

}
?>
```

Y me descarga el archivo, pero no podría ingresar el rango de fechas.
Saludos

Comment: Porque no usas Datatable y un filtro para el Datatable. El viene con botones para exportar excel, CSV, txt, pdf y mucho más. Después puedes reusar a lo largo del codigo